# How to store downloaded bitmaps into a Hash Map

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to download multiple images and want to store all downloaded images in a hash map and not in a cache, in order to prevent them from being downloaded again. How to store the downloaded bitmaps in a hash map?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) for this. If you employ ordinary HashMap, you should expect OutOfMemoryError.

So simply choose some identifier for the bitmaps and store them in the LruCache.

Comment: But still can u tell me how to to do using hash map.. I want to try using both techniques

Comment: Similar way as the LruCache. Simply create a HashMap (I assumed that the key is of type Long): HashMap<Long, Bitmap> map = new HashMap<Long, Bitmap>();. And then you can put items into the HashMap: map.put(id, bitmap);. The LruCache is a map that implements least recently used caching algorithm. So it gives you a memory usage control and prevents OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: I need to put the bitmap into the hash map, after downloading right. So it will have the same id for all bitmaps right? Doesn;t it create a problem?

Comment: No. You have to assign different ID for each Bitmap. The ID is your key with which you identify the bitmap. If you add to the map two bitmaps with the same ID, one will replace the other.

Comment: k i got it, i need to pass the url and bitmap after downloading. I'm using list view, So i need to check whether the bitmap exists in the hash map or not, if exists i need to retrieve it right or else i need to download

Comment: But how do i do that. I mean I receive bitmap after downloading right..then how to check whether bitmap is stored or not, before calling the download method?

Comment: I tried something like this:         Bitmap value=urlMap.get(imageUrl);
     if(value!=null){
  ImageDownloader downloader=new ImageDownloader();
  downloader.download(imageUrl,viewHolder.imageView);
     }
     else
      viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(value);
  return convertView;

Comment: If the map returns null, then download it and put into the map. ImageUrl String can be your key.